# Stern Gerlach experiment vs Zeeman effect

Tags: quantum-mechanics, physical-chemistry, atoms

In the Stern-Gerlach experiment, we discover that electrons have an intrinsic angular momentum, that we happen to call "spin". They applied a magnetic field to a source of atoms (originally, Ag), and found a decoupling into two energy levels, corresponding to the spin magnetic quantum numbers $m_s=1/2$ and $m_s=-1/2$.

The choice of Ag is important, because having an electron configuration of [Kr]$4d^{10} 5s^1$, the magnetic field should not result in decoupling of their energies due to the Zeeman effect, which becomes apparent only for $m_l\neq0$.

My problem is the following: while it is clear why hydrogen-like atoms with $m_l=0$ do not result in three bands, why did Zeeman not see the two bands from $m_s=\pm1/2$ as in the Stern-Gerlach experiment?